# Docker using VMWare Workstation: mount volume outside Users

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use Docker on Windows 7 with VMWare workstation (not Hyper-V, not VirtualBox).  I would like to mount a folder outside of `C:\Users` to the docker VM so it will be available for `volume` mapping in `docker-compose`.

```
volumes:
  - //c/source:/opt/app
```

The [Docker volumes documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) says

> If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker Engine
>   daemon has only limited access to your macOS or Windows filesystem.
>   Docker Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (macOS) or C:\Users
>   (Windows) directory.

But my code lives outside the `C:\Users` folder.  I need to mount `C:\source` to the container from Windows.

Could I mount a volume to the VM at startup?  If so, what would the command look like, and where would I run that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working for me was to simply create a symbolic link from the `C:\Users` folder to my source folder on the root.

```
C:\Users>mklink /d source c:\source\
symbolic link created for source <<===>> c:\source\
```

And now my compose volumes config looks like this

```
volumes:
  - /c/Users/source/myApp1:/app
```

Using VMWare Workstation 12.5.7 build-5813279

**How you star the Docker machine matters**

You must start the docker machine from the command line, such as

```
docker-machine start
```

Selecting start from the VMWare workstation GUI will not share the `Users` file.  There is something in the `docker-machine start` script which is necessary to share the `Users` folder.

You'll see the `Users` folder shared in the VMWare settings, but don't be lulled into thinking this setting captures all of the necessary requirments to share.  Starting the VM from VMWare workstation is not sufficient to cause the sharing to occur.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know VMWare did support those admin directory symlink. +1

Comment: VMware will read links created in Windows and treat them as actual directories in linux.  But VMware will not allow linux to create symlinks in a Windows shared folder.  So it works for my purpose, but the functionality does not work in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have [VMware Tools for Linux Guests](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html)

That will allow you to define the [use of a shared folder](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_sharedfolder_adding.html)

[image: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/img/w_sharefolder_name.png]

In other words, this is not a docker issue, and more a VMWare setting issue.

Comment: This does not work.  When I add `C:` as the Host folder share, I only see the `Users` folder inside `C:`.  I tried adding `C:\source`, but the mapped name doesn't show up.  The VMWare folder sharing only seems to work when sharing a folder accessing `Users`.  This is likely what the manual meant by saing "**your Docker Engine daemon has only limited access to your macOS or Windows filesystem**"